# Get leading alpha characters from a string in Java/Groovy

Tags: java, groovy

What is the best approach to get the leading alpha characters from a string using Java or Groovy? Is there an approach using a regEx parse or should I just use a for..loop to build a string w/ the leading alpha digits until a numeric character is found? If regex, what would a regex parse look like for this.

I have this type of string TT1703408513T and need just the leading the TT, but the leading alpha string can be 1-5 chars in length until a numeric value is found.

Update: This might not be the most efficient way, but it works.

```
String i= "TT1703408513T";
String o= "";
for( int x; x<i.length(); x++){
   if( i[x].matches("^[a-zA-Z]") )
      o += i[x];
   else
      break;
}
println o;
```

Comment: "best" by which metric? Either looping manually or using regex would work, but for simplicity and compactness sake I'd just use a regex.

Comment: Thanks, what would a regex look like for this to just extract [a-zA-Z] up to a numeric value without knowing the actual length of the leading alpha bytes?

Comment: `^[a-zA-Z]+` would do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Groovy

Given

```
String i = "TT1703408513T";
```

And all acceptable characters:

```
def chars = ['A'..'Z','a'..'z'].flatten()
```

You can just do

```
def prefix = i.takeWhile { it in chars }
```

Or if you're desperate to use a regular expression, you can do:

```
def prefix = i.find(/\p{Alpha}+/)
```

Or indeed:

```
a.find(/[A-Za-z]+/)
```

Comment: I tried this and `def prefix = i.takeWhile { it in chars }`  returns an empty string...

Comment: what is `i` and what is `chars` in your test?  The above code works

Comment: @ou_ryperd https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/edit/5090279669366784

Comment: @tim_yates I don't want to belabour the point here. I started a chat here, where I can add an image: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209439/groovy-takewhile

Answer (score 0):

regexp variants

```
String i= "TT1703408513T"

def v1 = ( i=~/^[a-zA-Z]+/ ).find{true}
println v1

def v2 = i.replaceAll("^([a-zA-Z]+).*",'$1')
println v2
```

Answer (score 0):

### Java Solution

I faced the same problem where I needed to extract leading alpha chars from a string.
I used a small trick to achieve the same.

Say errorCode is the String from which we are trying to get the leading chars

```
String errorCode = "AC0000XYZ";
String httpErrorCode =  errorCode.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]+", " ").split(" ")[0];
//httpErrorCode  would contain "AC" now
```

It first replaces all non alpha chars with space, then splits the String on spaces, then selects the first element out of them.

***only place where it won't work is when you dont have leading alpha chars in string***